# On firing onBlur e.target() is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

In my react application, the following script is executed when onBlur is fired. But e.target is returning null. So I'm unable to retrieve the text entered to validate.

```
handleNameValidation({ target }) {
    console.log("The target is : ", target);
}
```

But, I have a similar script working fine when firing an onChange event.
Is this an expected behavior or how can I access the value when onBlur is fired.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks and Regards,
San

Comment: can you share the full code?

Comment: There is nothing much, this function is being invoked on onBlur. For sure this function gets the call, but e.target is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have lost context of the handler:

1) use class property fields

```
handleNameValidation = ({ target }) => {
    console.log("The target is : ", target);
}
```

2) bind context in contructor

```
construtctor(props){
  super(props);

  this.handleNameValidation = this.handleNameValidation.bind(this);
}

handleNameValidation({ target }) {
    console.log("The target is : ", target);
}
```

Comment: but OP isn't accessing `this` within the event handler, so why does this matter?

Comment: I have "this.handleNameValidation = this.handleNameValidation.bind(this);" in the constructor already, thanks but confuced.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/18kyz9v264

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <input onBlur={this.onBlur} />
    </div>;
  }

  onBlur = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target);
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```